# What's the purpose of passing a method to the base class in Javascript like the one below?

Tags: javascript

I've seen a tutorial where a possible function is passed to the parent like below:

```
class Car {
  constructor(door, engine, color){
    this.door = door;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.color = color;
  }
  carStats(){
    console.log('in car stats...');
  }
}

class SUV extends Car {
  constructor(door, engine, color, brand, carStats){
    super(door, engine, color, carStats){
    this.brand = brand;
    this.wheels = 5;
    this.cheap = true;
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility of overwriting the parent method if you pass another function to it?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it out for yourself?

Comment: Could you clarify *"a possible function is passed to the parent"* where is a function passed to the parent?

Comment: This code is not passing any function to a parent. I don't see the connection of the question with the code that accompanies it.

Comment: @Andy, it is going to be ignored, because JS ignores extra params, but I'm asking as a newbie because there could be a design reason why such extra parameter is created?

Comment: @2limin4tor that call to super of class SUV has 'carStats' being passed to the base.

Comment: Ah, so the question is: What happens if I pass more parameters than declared in the method definition?

Comment: @3limin4tor, that, and is there a common practice in Javascript where you pass a function to overwrite another function within a class?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `super`, you actually call the constructor for `Car`, but the `Car` constructor only expects 3 arguments, not 5.

You should be able to override the `carStats` method by redefining it, but I don't think this is considered to be best practice.

```
class SUV extends Car {
    constructor(door, engine, color, brand, carStats){
        super(door, engine, color);
        this.carStats = carStats;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

Comment: the SUV constructor has that 'carStats' that could be a function being passed to it when instantiated, then it passes to the base thru the call to SUPER, but why would the instructor of the video I was watching create a parameter like that, what's the reason behind it? Let's say if I pass a function object to the instance of SUV (that 'carStats' param), how can I use that to overwrite the carStats method in Car class, and is it a valid javascript syntax? Thanks